# Displaying news on category basis

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, pyrocms

I have created a news module in codeigniter(pyrocms) in which news is added on category basis

i am stucked in retreiving the news detail on the basis of category selected

my query for getting news details from frontend is:-

```
$result='';
$sql= "SELECT `default_news`.*,IFNULL(default_newscategoriesff.name,'N.A.') As category  FROM (`default_news`) LEFT outer  JOIN `default_newscategories` default_newscategoriesff on  default_newscategoriesff.id=`default_news`.`category` WHERE `default_news`.`active` = '1' ORDER BY `updated_on` DESC ";
$allnews = $this->db->query($sql)->result();    
return $allnews;
```

what will be the where condition for selecting the news details on category basis means if i click on national category it should display all the news under national category

Comment: could u pate ur default_news table?

Comment: it contains following fields

id,
name,
intro,
body,
category,
login-required
user,
updated_on,
active,
comments_enabled,
featured,
attachment

Comment: then, u can use Where category="UR REQUIRED CATEGORY"...

Comment: it has to be dynamic.for that only i want the query what will be the where condition means there will be many categories so what will be the where condition??

Comment: Nisha, we could only help if you give us the default_news and default_newscategories table structure.

Comment: default_news table consists following fields:-
id, name, intro, body, category, login-required user, updated_on, active, comments_enabled, featured, attachment

and default_newscategories consists following fields :-
'id','name','active'

Comment: So the id in default_newscategories is linked with category default_news right ??

Comment: ya right i have joined both the tables on the basis of category id

Comment: but b.name has to be dynamic whatever category user selects from front the related news should be displayed.in ur answer if i mention .name='national' then it will display only national news.i want something like shown in http://www.punjabkesari.in.it has many categories and if i click on national news it will show only national news and if i click on international then it will show only international news

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select a.id, a.name, b.name from default_news as a, default_newscategories as b where a.category=b.id and b.name='national' order by a.id desc;
```

Comment: but b.name has to be dynamic whatever category user selects from front the related news should be displayed.in ur answer if i mention .name='national' then it will display only national news.i want something like shown in http://www.punjabkesari.in
.it has many categories and if i click on national news it will show only national news and if i click on international then it will show only international news

Comment: you get that category name from the view to controller right. You should pass that category to the controller and user that name in .name='$category'

Comment: i am trying to access news/category but its displaying an error:-

An Error Was Encountered

The page you are trying to view does not exist and it also appears as if the 404 page has been deleted.